# When an API created in publisher portal, where does the api definition created (in wso2 folder directory)?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I wanted see where the yaml/json files of an api stored in wso2 directory.

Comment: [take a look please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API definition is only stored in the Registry database. It won't be stored in the physical file system.

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
Can you please provide the steps to access the registry and how to retrieve api definitions?

Comment: You can access the swagger definition as below https://host:port/api/am/store/v0.11/apis/<UUID>/swagger

Comment: I wanted to see them in registry database, can you help me on how can I do that?

Comment: The swagger files are stored in the Registry DB under the REG_CONTENT table.

Comment: Awesome, I was to access REG_CONTENT table, thanks for your help.
Asking for extra help, do you know where I can access the source code that puts the data into registry (especially swagger definition) ? I tried looking into git, but I didn't get any luck.